# Shower tile cracked horizontally in the middle wall

Tags: water, leak

I have remodeled the shower a year ago, and just noticed a crack in the middle part of wall horizontally. What could be the problem? Thanks for your help!
Jinsu

Comment: is it just that one ? maybe a pic would help solving the mystery